# How to make the WebProxy class to work with a NTLM+Basic Proxy

Tags: .net

There is a proxy configured to authenticate initially using the NTLM protocol and after the Basic authentication method. Both methods work correctly. If NTLM access is enabled, all internet browsers (IE, Chrome and Firefox) work. If the NTLM access is prohibited, only FF handles this situation correctly. Initially FF displays a dialog for the NTLM authentication, after pressing the dialog's Cancel button, it displays the second authentication dialog for the Basic method. By entering correct login and password, the FF accesses Internet. Other browsers cannot authenticate using the login and password.

There is a task to write a program working through the proxy using the Basic authentication method. It should use the [WebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.aspx) class.

I wrote two different methods to authenticate. the 1st one is uses the [NetworkCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) class instance directly with `WebProxy`.

```
static private IWebProxy GetProxy00(string proxy_address, string proxy_login, string proxy_password) {
  WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxy_address, true);
  proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxy_login, proxy_password);
  proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  return proxy;
}
```

The second method uses the [CredentialCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.aspx) class

```
static private IWebProxy GetProxy01(string proxy_address, string proxy_login, string proxy_password) {
  CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
  WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxy_address, true);
  cache.Add(proxy.Address, "Basic", new NetworkCredential(proxy_login, proxy_password));
  proxy.Credentials = cache;
  proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  return proxy;
}
```

Both methods are tested using the following code

```
string proxy_login = "here is login";
string proxy_password = "here is password";
string proxy_address = "here is proxy address";
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
req.Proxy = GetProxy00(proxy_address, proxy_login, proxy_password);
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
```

and both of them throw the `System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.` exception.

How is possible to authenticate with the Basic authentication method via the proxy using the WebProxy class?